# What logic does one use to solve this probability question?

Tags: probability

Bill, George, and Ross, in order, roll a die. The first one to roll an even number wins and the game is ended. What is the probability that Bill win the game ?. How I approached the question: Since Bill is the first one to roll the die, he has a $.5$ probability of winning the game, if he does win then the question is solved the probability is $.5$, however if he doesn't roll an even number he has still a probability of winning, this probability would be $(.5)^3$. It seems to me that the probability of him winning is $(0.5)^n$ where $n$ is the number of die rolls. Is my logic correct, if not how is the problem answered ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is somehow not bad. However it is not complete, because Bill can win at the first roll, the 4th roll, the 7th roll, etc etc. Let $X_n$ be the event that Bill wins at the $n$-th roll. Clearly $P(X_1)=\frac{1}{2}$ (you know this). $P(X_2)=P(X_3)=0$ because then it is not his game. $P(X_4)$ then Bill must not win one time, George must not win one time, and Ross neither, that together gives $(\frac{1}{2})^3$ and then Bill must win the fourth roll so $P(X_4)=(\frac{1}{2})^4$. In general we have:
\begin{align}
P(\text{ Bill wins }) &= P(\text{ Bill wins at the first roll, fourth roll, seventh roll,..})\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{3n+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{8}}\\
&=\frac{4}{7}
\end{align}
So Bill wins with probability $4/7$. You can check that the probability that George and Ross win is $2/7$ and $1/7$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

On the first round, Bill has a probability of winning of $0.5$.

Knowing that Bill did not win or lose on the first round, he has a probability of winning on the second round of $0.5^4$, This is because if he did not win or lose in the first round, the probability of that happening is $0.5^3$, and now the probability of his winning again is $0.5$.

Now, on the third round, his probability of winning is is $0.5^7$, by the same logic.

And so on.

Now we add up the probability he has of winning for every round, and we get a geometric series with reason $q=0.5^3$. His probability of winning is therefore:

$p = 0.5 + 0.5^4 + 0.5^7 + \cdots = 0.5 \times \frac{1}{1-0.5^3}$

Answer (score 2):

> How I approached the question: Since Bill is the first one to roll the die, he has a $.5$ probability of winning the game, if he does win then the question is solved the probability is $.5$, however if he doesn't roll an even number he has still a probability of winning, this probability would be $(.5)^3$

You are almost there.   Call a group of rolls by the three players a round.

Let $P_B$ be the probability that Bill wins the game.   Bill wins the game (starting from the first round) if either he wins the first round, or if *nobody* wins the first round *and* Bill wins the game *starting from the second round*.   Use your evaluation to build a recursive formula:

$$P_B= 0.5+0.5^3P_B$$

This is because the (conditional)probability that Bill wins the game when given nobody wins the first round, is equal to the probability that Bill wins the game — because they basically just start over again from the beginning.

Solve to find: $P_B\phantom{= 4/7}$

Likewise evaluate the probabilities that George wins the game and that Ross wins the game.   Comment on whether/why going first conveys any advantage and verify that the sum equals one.

> $P_G =0.5 P_B$ and $P_R=0.5^2P_B$ because of *some reason*.

Answer (score 1):

Good start! Rather, he wins on the first roll with probability $0.5,$ on the fourth roll with probability $(0.5)^4,$ on the seventh roll with probability $(0.5)^7,$ and so on. These are the only rolls on which he can win, and if he doesn't win on one of those rolls, then he loses with probability $1$ (that is, there is effectively no chance that the game will go on forever). Thus, since he can't win on multiple turns, then the probability of winning is $$\begin{eqnarray}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{3n+1}&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac12\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{3n}\\&=&\frac12\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{3n}\\&=&\frac12\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\left(\frac12\right)^3\right)^n\\&=&\frac12\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac18\right)^n,\end{eqnarray}$$ and using [the formula for the sum of a convergent geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), we have that the probability is $$\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac18}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{\frac78}=\frac12\cdot\frac87=\frac47.$$